# Jersey Constructor Injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey

I'm using Jersey 2 to build a REST API. My Resource is getting its data from a postgre database with JPA. Now I want to test the API but I don't know how I can inject a fake persistance layer object in my resource (I learned to do this with CDI, but I can't do this here)

Test:

```
public class Test extends JerseyTest{

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(Resource.class);
    }
...
```

Resource:

```
@Path("apath")
public class Resource {

    private PersistenceLayer layer = new PersistenceLayerJPA(); //How do I inject this to fake it in the test environment?
...
```

I know that I should use HK2 and an application binder (read on several threads here) but I don't know where to differentiate between the test and the real injection.

Thx in advance

Comment: Why can't you use CDI? And if you know that you need to inject a fake implementation for your test, why don't you create a constructor that lets you inject a fake implementation to your class (even if this constructor is never used in production)?

Comment: @JBNizet I would do this, but there's no possibility to call the constructor. The Resource Class is "constructed" by the test framework and I've found no possibilities to add constructor parameters...

Comment: Ah, so you're not doing unit tests, but integration tests. If you can't use CDI, then reinvent it. Use factories, that will return a fake implementation instead of the real one when you're in a test environment.

Comment: Had the same idea, but I've no idea how to recognize the test or productive environment.

Comment: `java -Dtest=true` for example. Or use a properties file.